# Fetch Public Pages feed with javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to create a custom "LikeBox" style widget using the javascript sdk, but it appears that I need an access token to fetch the feed data.  Since all the code is on the clientside, I don't really want the page access token visible to everybody.  What is the best way to handle this?

Here's the javascript api call that I'm doing that throws an error:

```
FB.api('/[page]/feed', function(data) { console.log(data); });
```

Error:

`error: Object
code: 104
message: "An access token is required to request this resource."
type: "OAuthException"`

Here's the solution: http://tutorialzine.com/2011/03/custom-facebook-wall-jquery-graph/

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution I went with:

http://tutorialzine.com/2011/03/custom-facebook-wall-jquery-graph/

Answer (score 0):

A page posts needs any valid access_token or user access_token to request the information. Seeing that you are doing this all client side I don't think it will be possible to hide the information (i.e. the access_token).

Your plugin should incorporate some server side authentication to take care of this.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

Comment: It sounds like either way I'd have to show the page access_token to the user because if the user is not logged in, I'd need to request a page access_token, which would then need to be sent down to the client.  Is that right?

Comment: @GregAllen not necessarily, you can use an app token so then you just need the app id and secret, no authorization needed. See here for more info http://philippeharewood.com/facebook/how-to-get-facebook-access-tokens-in-php-for-public-posts-the-basic-sauce/